# How to Localize End User License Agreement for iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app that I want to submit to Apple, which will be available worldwide; however, I can't find any documentation that outlines how to add specific file, or submit the EULA.

From the Apple docs it says:

> Apple provides a standard EULA that applies in all territories. You can provide a document that supersedes the Apple EULA for one or more countries. You can provide only one EULA per app, so this document needs to contain agreement text appropriate for each territory where you want to apply your custom EULA. For information about creating a EULA, see Instructions for Minimum Terms of Developer’s End-User License Agreement.

So my question is: How do you provide this document? Currently I have 40+ documents, one for each language I want to support, and I'm not sure if that is what I need to do, or have one document, which Apple will the put in the correct language for the territory it is being bought in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple licensing

Comment: @MikeW So asking questions about programming tools is off topic?

Comment: When was an EULA ever a programming tool?

Comment: @MikeW a EULA is not, but submitting an app via iTunes IS a programming tool, because it's part of the programming process for mobile apps. Not everything has to be code to be on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes Connect, there is a section under your app details that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I saw that. But do I need to add all 40 plus documents, or just add 1, and select each of the regions?

Comment: In that section it says "Select the countries in which your EULA applies. Select only the countries for which your EULA has been properly localized to meet local legal and language requirements. For all other countries, the standard EULA will apply."

how do you properly localize that document?

Comment: @Blaine The docs say you should include all your languages in that one field: "Your EULA text can include multiple languages."

Comment: So you are saying that I put all 40 docs into the one "custom" area?

Comment: I haven't done that before, but that's what the docs are saying.